# How to save pdf data coming from API to local machine using Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am integrating  Flipkart API with my Application. So i hit the API that gives me in response a PDF as follows:-

```
{ statusCode: 200,
I20160819-17:49:54.307(5.5)?   content: '%PDF-1.4\n%����\n2 0 obj\n<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 3559>>stream\nx��[Ys\u001b�\u0011~ǯ��$��\\͹\u0007�B��Ą�\bD���ÆX�p\u0016\u0000\u0005��U�\u001f�����.���*��>������\u0019~���M0*9��\u0012�擋�����\u0004g�\u0015\u0002�:��o��_&\u0004���O��h>!E�稤<�\u0004-\'�\u0000�X��4p\u0015@i��p�O�\u001f&�\t�8\u0003C\u0018\fQ0�\u0013ˈ@$\u0013%R�0���߁0��\n�DdU\u000ev\r�\t�8\u0007m�\t\u0007�,�0t����\u0014�@���\u0011ԑ,���R?\u0018�u4fYI�P\u0014{BZ����`K�� H~�9C�V�8p�R�W�V�qbim+���V�Ș�4��Hy,�ʌrE+vVd��*�\u001dͳ\u001c��0\u0013\u001d!�e\u0007{lc�\u0012\u001dc��p\u0014��`\u0019-\u0002m\u0005�\u0004U4�c���A2LE\u001e�F�^\b>�Rm��\u001a���Š�\u001dP��}���;�:\u000e�0IC��?\u0018�a�Cv&�@�F\u000e\u001er\u0004j�\u0005\u0015�ߧ�\u000fY;H@V\b睦}�D�UU��҇\u0006H[�\u0001�\u0001\u000f����К�Y��{��\u001d��h#_y��X����O}�+���o5�}��\u0018��\u000f����}�c\u0015�ߧ?��E���H۱\u001f�6�����U���M#���#�f�n���!��q�\u0006s��\u0000X��4�C�#�1$���\u001eTQJ�L�1�t��FƏ2\u001eUl~�~�`�\u0015V\b�0�M�C�N����Xp;�� &�cy\u001d�Ct�\\�ڭ�fܓ{F\u001d�\u0018�Uf���ښ�L�1�t��\u0004\t�\u0012A�l�Q2X$ɒJ\u0010*�.�9�奥[OC��\n0K)݆�\u000bش�\u0004�\u001c�j\u0003\n\u000b���iY\u0002e\u001e�����&Z\u0005dkI^��4�\ti��$����[��\f*�\u0019,xe� \n�+)�3��l9�\u000e���;Ä�9g\u0002��g���\\�ӎ����g���?��#�<?1�D2��\u0007�\u0019\u0016\u0007.�s�7\u0015��\u0001c �Tm��Җ]���Y\u0006^\u0015b��dD�\u0007\'P�m:;7�>#\n[�f�<L\u00052�����&\u001e���b����\u001a}8 ��\b��d�j�֑yV\u0006����j֔�.��2?6�G�1$���U���:��\u0001.K��y�+)ꆢI\'\u0002���\u0000��á\u00040b����Jt֭���aH� @�XX�[:¡�z\u001c\u001e|hb��xr��h�W��.9����\u0013������\u0014�\u0019ݝ^M�\u0010!9�;B��a��\u001c���\b�{�<�����z��^�\u0019|���w��7�8Yf�\u001aS�����v��|=A�P�O\u000b�<�\\\t\u0011J1&�D\'\u0019���\u001506�+)�S�\u0012V&-�\u0012A�2�\u0017�x:{=��A7�\u000e�D�A\u0007\u000bn�\u0016���e�\u001f��Mg`2s6\u0007�.�+��-<I\u0013��4)��j7\f���eW\bSPh\u0011C��t\u0015�f.�j�}!���U��\t\n����b�T��h,\u001eʖ\u0017;����xq�#:=?���Nǂb\u0014\u0014�Up�xDd�;B[=�\u0019���~F��qu�n�zs�Bp�Q���}EO���bW�G�\tc+|Y������\u0005:F�`�/G�������D�A.e��&��9:[�-�\n����j�N��6C\u0005��T���/,���z���\u001b\u0016c�@u�N��������\u000b[Y�˴�v�������[z|�~�=m�z����n���Kۢi�4_\u001a\u0004�b1G���/��\u0006�Mm���i�ٍ�FK�ʺt�$ѕ��e�H\u00120^�yƅ�X1`������]\u0015:\u0001�a\u001e\r�X\u001b^&�\u0011�\u000f�q]�Vrߕܟ����=zs{����cZ���\t\t\n2\u0013\u0014R\u0012�T��^��_�\rڭ����k����b�[<l]ub�\u0012�C\u0015*��\u0002�@-c�\u0013b��$�$\b(�%~\u000eIɔA��\\��$\u0015�UQ\u0014�Qa�G���{\u001d��9\f���K�*�B����Qt^b}\u001ek�jB;~Y�}F�_\u001bw蟨<\u0004�I\\��V�\u000fj����9(�\u0000[\t\u001bOPIY�VMQQ�)��\u0005h��\n�v.7\u0002=�:1G�$�@���e�\u0000�����d$mP��\u001cO)7�o(�����5}��\u001b���\u001d7\u000ba\u0012��+uV\u0007�}=\u001cц�z|�]�-\u0003%��r��&]�Eu\u0017��]S4R㱼��\u0004\u001c*/\u0011��f� ��_\u001e��[�"��\u0013�)�M\u0018Q�i���\\�O}!���,��ʠr�\u001bZ^\u0018��c\u0001S\t3�S�L�L�K\u001cZ`0#?����%eJ���2T\u0015\u0016k��k$�Xue)�^UY�\n�&I���YJ5\u001c�\u0015\u0013�=���ѭ��"��,�UM��3M�U��څ�(�\\}Y/\u001e�N���9X!\u001b\\/�\u0016_�S��\'�q�p�\n�\u0018-a\u000b���׻���c�8�m�WK1ɏqyL�#���(�����)�@@��N!�\u0012��nh�e��G�N�R(\u0003י�c>�r�a�P�g�B�����������\u0014�\f�@����>�����?��D�9�d�fQVx���V;���\u001e��{<O\u0011��\u001c\u0001f9is����]�h�k4K��G\u0016�\u0017L�i�\u001a�Y���\b\u0005x_MPfzp���\u0016ܐT\u0016���6�������\u0019\n%[\tZ!�\u0016:\u0013M�\u0016���8ʴ=�e4�\u0007�@E�u\r�8+\'��?�5\u001d��\u0013�A�Xh�kڣ�a�������\u0001\u0004��_\u000f]?�LZ�c�@��N*B����n�D(�Sҍ����\u0015����j��9�;\b�X {��n��a\u001c���?\u0013��\t�^��BӇR\u0007EO���%GgC�Т>��S�qi\u001f�΁ܸ���;�C����a1��4��|�\u0002\u0019Q\u001d�\u0019��$$B!�V�lI}�i�+噽S�I����\u0014^�%C\u0005���+ʉ�*\u0012��\u0012�Y�̝�<,�^�%����T$>�۩�>�$�=��`I���8\u001f�.�x�2�N�L\u0002\u0002�<=����h\u0002I�0<\u0016D��c�qG("�0\u000e�ay0\u001b,ma$��3\r��\u0011��Zv�Ѥ�,�{9�\u0015,@bi\u001b�\u0004��\u001f�L.,\u0011��e�\u001f!�,���p�X�"I���8��!��u-;�\bId\u0019z\u0011y�\u0016���\u0016I�L�\u0005\u001a&�$Bֵ��C$�e@�\u000byU��X�XN�i%��"��u-;�\bId\u0019�TX��x$��H\u0012dZ�arH"d]ˎ?B\u0012Y�<ę|J��8�"I��\\f�\u001c�\bYײ�\u000f�Ė�.�9$�6�SdQV�Jt\u001e�J4��\u0018�\u0018���\f\'\u001e^\u0017~��\u0019Nk}\u001b�a��K��t�#�\u001anOIn\u001fKg����\u0018\b!��M�\u001baHr�X&����ɢ\bAu�:�h�Nr�h\u001e�����\u0006$�յ��#\u001cif\u001f�b���0Y\u001c!��]�\u001d�H��X\u000e������\bau�:�\u0010G��G3XoV7L\u0006G\u0004�k�qG8Ҝ>���s�a�8BX]��;d���ӛ�-��\u0011���u�!�4��\t�����y�Em�uJL���\u00127F�T��غ�{U�u�`\u0012�+�\r\u000bL� \r+�S�\u001b֨F��x4�.޾<ny\f�\u0010N�bo�0v���1�i�����W�l��/v��j�N��ۯ\u0019�k�z۠M���n�=5�Y_Ѣ���A?�7h��4h�\u000eƶI��oT�����[�\u0016[\u0004�k��^>����c�j6�>/K�=�\u0003J����yK������4�3m�\u0016��7��I]Y�ӕ�C\u001at��|\u0007\u0012���\u001d:�\u0015k"C���1:�z��� \u001a��%x�bz�,�\u0005�QYRy1��24\u000fm\r^�X\u000f��1r�Ѩ�W�\u001e���\u0016m�iE\r�_�v�j\u000e��S\u0001~B/[��\u0003L����2P×��N1�\u0007�6\u000ei�d\u0004�\r,�B}��n\u001f6\u000b�kPN��ʛM\'h��w�\u0012]�\u000f��D��N4yP��\b�\b\t\u0004�60UGn@�<��"\n��t6r���c\u0017/e�c\u0007�8!\u0019\u0006[�;]���#��B�;V:�\u0016W/A<B��`t`\u001c*x\u001c��/�\u000f��Ƞ����xjl�Ȏ�,DE%o\u001d�$>��\u0007\n�`\u001cb\u0000� �-�z�\u0011=0�\t���Wt���S�����\u0005�\u001f,��\u0010լ��_�\u001a>�&L\u001dAy,"��\u0019�i#jV{q2\f\u000f��"��\u0017ф\r\u000bq!��@H��\u0017�2��@\b�\u001a\u0014�4��?\u0007��\u000b��\u0004T���Y\u0017VkY\f\u001f\u0006s��PeB=b��}����uş>}?((��7�\u0001�����6,\nk�iU��!����vvz�>�~<A�ςx��V�rkK���_�]��7]�N\u0011�\u0017IO\u0012n��)��/u��l͆�.o��\u000b\u0005\u000e3\u001e�{�`��Ѿn\u0004�wF�A�eȝ<3��ʠd��3�D\u0006;~e ��������\t�\nendstream\nendobj\n4 0 obj\n<</ColorSpace/DeviceGray/Subtype/Image/Height 33/Filter/FlateDecode/Type/XObject/Width 145/BitsPerComponent 8/Length 834>>stream\nx�ŗ}�� \f��@\u0004"\u0010�\bF �\u0011��\bD �"\u0018�\bD�e\u001b����z�}��\u001f��0�~lch�}F�8¹��?İ\u0013DC?ި1��9��\u0000\u0015_�C\u0019�X����/���@\u0006t�� @��8\u000f��@g��.}\u0012��<�_\u0001M�)���@�k t�\u0002r��\u001aP�\u0001��\bm�����uuQ>\u0010��U�Z\u0005��0?\u0002�6�\u0005\u0001�}�g���:\u0006�S�������]ى�J���=��$S\u0015���\u001dv�y�~�\u0013\u000e*XW�(��\'��\u0018��\u0001�~\u0012�\u0001�,V\u0002\u0007\u001f�r�\u0005�\u0011B*_\u0000�JWc;�pD���1�.�\u0019�����o�H��\u001dp*���`���|J&�\u001d\u001cρj�\u0012 �O���p\u0003D�@e��\u000f\u001c�\n7H\u0005\u0006پ�\f�����s 咋+�%{A��\u001aHwq*�q���H^E\u0011�w\u0005�\n�u�\u001d�d�2\\\u0003�e�\u00027tRI�\r\u0012G�w5TSg)@��\u0005�O�h�\u001a�N����g^O��\u0006ҍ�\u001d2���p8X�9�vb�Q���\u001a\t�Y��\u0002��\u0003�.܃�\u001aNɬm�D\u000e(���6ı�#sK\fg�\u0015�����\u0001�5[-\u0000�2��*f�\u0014J\u0016�\u0003�\u0000�*��噰�z�nlg �h�\u0013q\u0001$�\u0011ɪ��\u0005��d��:o\u001dI"(������A�\u0001�\u0000��Pk�R\rm\\\u000e!����Nv�va�ˮ{�\u0003���r\rek��|��,K~k\u0007�C6Q���2Il9�9jmm\u0006w\u0007$W\u000f>\u0000Q8�\u0002��9Y��al���\u001beQ��lܩ ��2�|�x\u001e�W�t\u0007\u0014�vZ�c\u0016\'�-8J>F�\u001b��Lu��-�s)�7�e��cع��; \u0007�}�����\n�\u0019J5�\u0013��m�f�\u0002_��Ϊ�g��\u0000K�lDL�)��;�[{�9Е��\u0015G��c�����\u0017^Ⱦ\u00064G�%Tÿ����fʏ?��A�G���w@T����7@�q��9��y��\u0006�Ҡ�6���\bă�]*?��u\u0019�<rD�GGئ�\u0003v��y\nendstream\nendobj\n3 0 obj\n<</ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/Height 33/Filter/FlateDecode/Type/XObject/Width 145/SMask 4 0 R/BitsPerComponent 8/Length 37>>stream\nx���\u0001\r\u0000\u0000\u0000 �Om\u000e7�\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0003\u00038\u0013\u0000\u0001\nendstream\nendobj\n5 0 obj\n<</ColorSpace/DeviceGray/Subtype/Image/Height 127/Filter/FlateDecode/DecodeParms<</Columns 127/Colors 1/Predictor 15/BitsPerComponent 1>>/Type/XObject/Width 127/BitsPerComponent 1/Length 220>>stream\nx�Ŕ�\u0011� \fE�υKF�(l\u0006x3F�\b�.8~$q�e���p�FBz\u0012�v�\u001ex=�\u000e8\u0001�\r[\u000f��\b\'@��7䤃\u001av\t@����=�t4�\u001e@\u001fre~\u0015y\u0005��a��H�\t4�\t��hqx\u0001�r\n\u0013,�\n���\u001czK+�\u0013\u0010aTI ��A�\u00078�\u001c\u0000���\b�02s;k~4\u000b\u001fАM~V�Qw\u0002 �M\u0001>{l\u0005�<\u0014d�r8\u0001�\u001a�柎�\u0000\t�����_\u0004L\u0016^�\u001cˬ�\u0007��j��Jc+�\u0007���\u0000�KQ�\nendstream\nendobj\n6 0 obj\n<</ColorSpace/DeviceGray/Subtype/Image/Height 30/Filter/FlateDecode/DecodeParms<</Columns 199/Colors 1/Predictor 15/BitsPerComponent 1>>/Type/XObject/Width 199/BitsPerComponent 1/Length 82>>stream\nx�c��\u0003�cb�\u0005�,���d�\\�=�Տ�u�\u0018�\u001f�4i�zJ��c\u000ets���`�a��\u0013���%��妲�s3���<o�Y�fu�^.\u0000\u0000��2#\nendstream\nendobj\n7 0 obj\n<</ColorSpace/DeviceGray/Subtype/Image/Height 199/Filter/FlateDecode/DecodeParms<</Columns 30/Colors 1/Predictor 15/BitsPerComponent 1>>/Type/XObject/Width 30/BitsPerComponent 1/Length 110>>stream\nx��RA\n�0\b[{ٷ��� \u001b+L\b��؃hM��v\u0000w?���jmL�\u0004�\f?/�\u0011\u0012�\u0012$���\u000b\b�I�\f,\u0005d��Ƴ\u0019\u0018�\u001a4Ym_J�2�,^�Uƴ?!��������%\u001f��flA�~�\u0000�\u0017Ո\nendstream\nendobj\n8 0 obj\n<</Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Times-Roman/Type/Font/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>\nendobj\n9 0 obj\n<</Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Times-Bold/Type/Font/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>\nendobj\n1 0 obj\n<</Contents 2 0 R/Type/Page/Resources<</ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI]/XObject<</img4 3 0 R/img3 4 0 R/img2 5 0 R/img1 6 0 R/img0 7 0 R>>/Font<</F1 8 0 R/F2 9 0 R>>>>/Parent 10 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 595.28 841.88]>>\nendobj\n10 0 obj\n<</Kids[1 0 R]/Type/Pages/Count 1>>\nendobj\n11 0 obj\n<</Type/Catalog/Pages 10 0 R>>\nendobj\n12 0 obj\n<</ModDate(D:20160819174952+05\'30\')/CreationDate(D:20160819174952+05\'30\')/Producer(iText� 5.3.2 �2000-2012 1T3XT BVBA \\(AGPL-version\\))>>\nendobj\nxref\n0 13\n0000000000 65535 f \n0000006095 00000 n \n0000000015 00000 n \n0000004631 00000 n \n0000003642 00000 n \n0000004833 00000 n \n0000005278 00000 n \n0000005583 00000 n \n0000005916 00000 n \n0000006006 00000 n \n0000006330 00000 n \n0000006382 00000 n \n0000006429 00000 n \ntrailer\n<</Info 12 0 R/ID [<147c397002389b125c8708fb1bfd240a><6e61d7312c91691f41f860d9971d0b4b>]/Root 11 0 R/Size 13>>\n%iText-5.3.2\nstartxref\n6583\n%EOF\n',
I20160819-17:49:54.307(5.5)?   headers: 
I20160819-17:49:54.307(5.5)?    { server: 'nginx/1.4.4',
I20160819-17:49:54.307(5.5)?      date: 'Fri, 19 Aug 2016 12:19:54 GMT',
I20160819-17:49:54.308(5.5)?      'content-type': 'application/pdf',
I20160819-17:49:54.308(5.5)?      'content-length': '7006',
I20160819-17:49:54.308(5.5)?      connection: 'keep-alive',
I20160819-17:49:54.308(5.5)?      'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=Flipkart-Labels-19-Aug-2016-05-49.pdf',
I20160819-17:49:54.308(5.5)?      vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
I20160819-17:49:54.308(5.5)?      'x-e-id': '10.85.48.130',
I20160819-17:49:54.309(5.5)?      'content-security-policy-report-only': 'default-src  \'self\'; script-src  \'self\'; object-src  \'self\'; style-src  \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\'; img-src  \'self\'; media-src  \'self\'; frame-src  \'self\'; connect-src  \'self\'; report-uri https://seller.flipkart.com/appErrors',
I20160819-17:49:54.309(5.5)?      'x-xss-protection': '1;mode=block',
I20160819-17:49:54.309(5.5)?      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000;preload',
I20160819-17:49:54.309(5.5)?      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff' },
I20160819-17:49:54.309(5.5)?   data: null }
```

when i hit the same API via postman that will automatically save the pdf into my local machine. I want the same , just wondering to know how we can save the coming content into a pdf file in my local machine.

As i tried with **fs and pdfkit**  modules to achieve this but every time i tried with this it just simple write the content as shown above to the file those are not readble. So what should i use here so that the pdf data coming from API directly save to my system in pdf format.

Any help would be appriciated

Thanks!

Comment: @praveen you are using request module